# MQL4 question How open multiple orders in EA

Tags: mql4

I still don't know how code to open multiple orders in EA.
I saw some EA open orders multiple times example buy order open first time and next buy order will open after direction is correct.
How can code it.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *How open multiple orders in EA?*

for example this way:

```
#define NotSetHERE 0.
int retCode = OrderSend( _Symbol,    // string   symbol,               // symbol
                         OP_BUY,     // int      cmd,                  // operation
                         1.0,        // double   volume,               // volume
                         Ask,        // double   price,                // price
                         10,         // int      slippage,             // slippage
                         NotSetHERE, // double   stoploss,             // stop loss
                         NotSetHERE, // double   takeprofit,           // take profit
                         "DEMO1",    // string   comment     = NULL,   // comment
                         -1,         // int      magic       = 0,      // magic number
                         0,          // datetime expiration  = 0,      // P/O expiration
                         clrRed      // color    arrow_color = clrNONE // color
                         );
...
...

int retCod2 = OrderSend( "XAGUSD",   // string   symbol,               // symbol
                         OP_BUY,     // int      cmd,                  // operation
                         2.0,        // double   volume,               // volume
                         Ask,        // double   price,                // price
                         10,         // int      slippage,             // slippage
                         NotSetHERE, // double   stoploss,             // stop loss
                         NotSetHERE, // double   takeprofit,           // take profit
                         "DEMO2",    // string   comment     = NULL,   // comment
                         -2,         // int      magic       = 0,      // magic number
                         0,          // datetime expiration  = 0,      // P/O expiration
                         clrWhite    // color    arrow_color = clrNONE // color
                         );

...
...

int retCod3 = OrderSend( "EURCHF",   // string   symbol,               // symbol
                         OP_BUY,     // int      cmd,                  // operation
                         3.0,        // double   volume,               // volume
                         Ask,        // double   price,                // price
                         10,         // int      slippage,             // slippage
                         NotSetHERE, // double   stoploss,             // stop loss
                         NotSetHERE, // double   takeprofit,           // take profit
                         "DEMO3",    // string   comment     = NULL,   // comment
                         -3,         // int      magic       = 0,      // magic number
                         0,          // datetime expiration  = 0,      // P/O expiration
                         clrGreen    // color    arrow_color = clrNONE // color
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks you and how close all this order in one point .Some will lose some will profit but close all at the same point.